# Prestashop custom hook doesn't shows

Tags: hook, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I created a custom hook as the PrestaShop docs states, and after several tries I still can't get it displayed in front. It shows in the back and in the *Positions* page, though ¿Is there anything I'm not doing right?
The hook

```
    public function displayProductsListBottom($params)
    {
        $this->context->smarty->assign(
            array(
            'logged'             => $this->context->customer->isLogged(),
            'module_textbanner_title' => Configuration::get('module_textbanner_title'),
            'module_textbanner_subtitle' => Configuration::get('module_textbanner_subtitle'),
            'module_textbanner_content' => Configuration::get('module_textbanner_content')
            )
        );

         $this->context->controller->registerStylesheet(
              'module-textbanner',
              'modules/'.$this->name.'/views/css/module_textbanner.css',
                  array('position' => 'top', 'priority' => 150)
                );
        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/front/ps_module_textbanner.tpl');
    }
```

The registration

```
    {
        if (!parent::install()
            || !$this->registerHook('displayProductsListBottom')
        ) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The *theme.yml*

```
  configuration:
    PS_IMAGE_QUALITY: png
  modules:
   to_enable:
     - ps_linklist
   to_disable:
     - ps_searchbar
  hooks:
    custom_hooks:
        name: displayProductsListBottom
        title: displayProductsListBottom
        description: Adds some content to products list
    modules_to_hook:...
```

The template:

```
<div id="js-product-list">
  {*<div class="products">*}
    {foreach from=$listing.products item="product"}
      {block name='product_miniature'}
        {include file='catalog/_partials/miniatures/product.tpl' product=$product}
      {/block}
    {/foreach}
  {*</div>*}


  {block name='pagination'}
    {include file='_partials/pagination.tpl' pagination=$listing.pagination}
  {/block}

  {hook h='displayProductsListBottom' mod='ps_module_textbanner'}

  <div class="visible--mobile text-right up">
    <a href="#header" class="btn btn-secondary">
      {l s='Back to top' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}
      <i class="material-icons">&#xE316;</i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a small mistake :)

`public function displayProductsListBottom($params)`

should be:

`public function hookDisplayProductsListBottom($params)`

Comment: So much thanks!!! This may sound silly, but  I couldn't see what was.